# twig macros argument is a combination of a string and a variable

Tags: twig

Hello I'm having problems with a macro.

in macros.html.twig

```
{% macro panel_header(title) %}
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ title|escape('html') }}
    </div>
{% endmacro %}
```

in profile.show.html.twig

```
{% import "macros.html.twig" as macros %}
{{ macros.panel_header("hello"  {{profile.name}} ) }}
```

Above example doesn't work because it asks that arguments are separated by a comma

```
{{ macros.panel_header("hello  {{profile.name}}" ) }}
```

This outputs "hello {{profile.name}} which makes sense ofcourse

So my question is how can i add a string and a variable as a single argument to a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation `(#{expression})` allows any valid expression to appear within a double-quoted string. The result of evaluating that expression is inserted into the string:

```
{{ "foo #{bar} baz" }}
{{ "foo #{1 + 2} baz" }}

{{ macros.panel_header("hello #{profile.name}") }}
```

String interpolation was added in Twig 1.5

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators

> ~: Converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. {{ "Hello " ~ name ~ "!" }} >would return (assuming name is 'John') Hello John!.

So in my example this works:

```
{{ macros.panel_header("hello" ~ profile.name ) }}
```

Comment: I think you mean to add a space after the hello: "hello " ~ profile.name, otherwise you'll end up outputting "hellomilio" instead of "hello milio"